# Simba Cassandra Tableau SparkSQL NullPointerException

Tags: cassandra, tableau-api, datastax-enterprise, simba

I am trying to analyze data stored in DSE 4.8.3 Cassandra using Tableau through SparkSQL.

Following is the description of column family I Created in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE demokeyspace.temp (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    id int
)
```

The above table has only 1 row:

```
cqlsh> select * from demokeyspace.temp;

 name       | id
 ------------+----
 helloworld |  1

(1 rows)
```

One piece of info: I have replicated 'demokeyspace' keyspace on all the nodes of my cluster to make sure all the nodes can access it.

I have installed ODBC Administrator and Simba Spark ODBC Driver into the list of Drivers. I have enabled the thrift server on the node (spark5.xxx.xxx)

I am able to connect to the my Cassandra table from Tableau using SparkSQL.

My issue is when I drag the temp to the workspace and then click on 'Update Now' I am getting the following error:

[image]

When I click on the 'Show Query':

```
SELECT 1 AS `number_of_records`,
  `temp`.`id` AS `id`,
  `temp`.`name` AS `name`
FROM `demokeyspace`.`temp` `temp`
LIMIT 1000
```

Any idea why I am finding this error and/ or how I can fix this.

Comment: Can you share the version of the Spark driver you're using, along with a driver trace (see the install guide for the driver) of the problematic run?

Comment: I am using Spark version 1.4.2

Comment: I want to add 1 more thing. This error still persists. But I created another keyspace named 'tableaudemo'  and created the same column family in that keyspace. It worked. Now I am not sure why this is running for the new keyspace but giving the same error for the 'demokeyspace' keyspace.

Comment: Interesting. If you're able to provide the driver log I may be able to shed some light on this.